React Native Error: A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called, JS engine: Hermes
I’m encountering an error in my React Native project when trying to run the app. The error message is as follows:
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called, JS engine: Hermes


change my index.js code
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry, AppState} from 'react-native'; // Combined import from 'react-native'
import App from './App'; // Main component import
import {name as appName} from './app.json'; // Import the app name from app.json
import './src/utils/i18n'; // Import for internationalization
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'; // Import Firebase Messaging
import store from './src/redux/store/store'; // Redux store
import * as FcmSlice from './src/redux/slices/FcmSlice'; // Redux slice for FCM
import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens'; // Optimize navigation using screens
import 'react-native-reanimated'; // For animations in React Native

enableScreens(); // Enables optimized screens for better navigation performance

// Firebase background message handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  if (AppState.currentState === 'background') {
    // Dispatch the message to the Redux store
    store.dispatch(FcmSlice.getfcmMessage(remoteMessage));
  }
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

// Register the main app component
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);


The error you're encountering indicates that there's an issue with loading a module, which is preventing the registration of your main application component with AppRegistry. Here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve this:

Make sure your main application component is correctly exported. For example
import App from './App'; // Adjust path as necessary
AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourAppName', () => App);

Clear Cache:
npx react-native start --reset-cache

Check Hermes Configuration:
In your android/app/build.gradle, check for the following:
project.ext.react = [
enableHermes: true  // If set to false, switch to true
]

Rebuild the App:
npx react-native run-android   # for Android
npx react-native run-ios       # for iOS

Look for Dependency Issues:
npm install
or
yarn install


If you've gone through these steps and still have issues, feel free to provide more details about your setup or any specific error messages, and I can help you troubleshoot further!

Thank you for the detailed response! It was really helpful, and I appreciate the time you took to explain React Native Error: A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.register component wasn't called, JS engine: Hermes
